# How to add conditional formatting to list items in CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am building a notice board that consists out of three categories. `Error`, `Warning`, and `Information`. The colors of these items being `red`, `orange` and `green` respectively. However I only want the colors to be applied to the `bullets`.

This is the list:

```
<ul class='well well-large custom-bullet'>
        <li >First item</li>
        <li >Second item</li>
        <li >Third item</li>
        <li >Fourth item</li>

    </ul>
```

Like you can see, I have a `custom-bullet` class, which just turns the `list items` into a bootstrap glyphicon.

The css class:

```
.custom-bullet li{
        display:block;
    }
    .custom-bullet li:before{

    content: "\e034";
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-size: 9px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: -17px;
    color: #CCCCCC;
    }
```

So what I want, is to conditionally format the bullet items to correlate with the categories. Now I will provide the conditional and the database values however I want to know how will I be able to link my conditional with the css coloring?

Comment: Simple, if you will send 3 values from db like error, warning and information then grab them in class or role and grab with jquery and give css on the base of that jquery's value..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give each `li` a `class`. Get that specific `li` by putting the `class name` in the CSS like this : `.custom-bullet li.red::before` (Here `red` is the class name). Now you can provide the `color` for the `li` separately.

```css
.custom-bullet li{
        display:block;
    }
.custom-bullet li.red::before{
    content: "\e034";
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-size: 9px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: -17px;
    color: red;
    }

.custom-bullet li.green::before{

    content: "\e034";
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-size: 9px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: -17px;
    color: green;
    }
.custom-bullet li.yellow::before{

    content: "\e034";
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-size: 9px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: -17px;
    color: yellow;
    }
.custom-bullet li.blue::before{

    content: "\e034";
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-size: 9px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: -17px;
    color: blue;
    }
```

```html
<ul class='well well-large custom-bullet'>
        <li class="red">First item</li>
        <li class="green">Second item</li>
        <li class="yellow">Third item</li>
        <li class="blue">Fourth item</li>

    </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, will try doing that. Will tie an if statement to a variable and then output the variable as a class.